# Quotas in PHP and onClick

Tags: php, html

When I try to use this:

```
<?php
$html = "<p id="test"><input class='is' id='live' type='checkbox' onclick='update(".htmlspecialchars($myid).");'></p>";
?>
```

If `$myid` is a number the above works fine. If it contains text like `mytext_30`, then `onClick` I get a console message that `mytext_30` is not defined. How in the top syntax I can include some kind of quotas for the result to be always like this:

```
<input .... onclick='update("30")'/> or
<input .... onclick='update("mytext_30")'/>
```

?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: change `"` to `'` for `id ` attribute

Comment: I did,  but this was not the issue(i suppose you know that already)

Comment: is `update` a js function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quotes you are using are mislead for PHP. try this:

```
$html = "<p id=\"test\"><input class='is' id=\"live\" type='checkbox' onclick='update(\"".htmlspecialchars($myid)."\");'></p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem belongs to missing escaping of the quotes. Thats easy to fix.

But first, you should decide on a way you will use. Preferred way to write tags in HTML is to always use quotes `"`. But at least, you should not mix quotes and apostrophes. Decide for one way and use them, but not switch between them *here and there*.

The best way here is, to use quotes for the tags, and apostrophe for the php string. With using apostrophes for this, you have clean HTML and don't need to escape anything.

```
$html = '<p id="test"><input class="is" id="live" type="checkbox" onclick="update(' . htmlspecialchars($myid) . ');"></p>';
```